# windows 10 C:\ is not accessible

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions

ok so this is a common issue that seems to have many causes. After attempting to install a standalone SDK .exe the installer quit when almost completed and indicated a permissions error.
I tried simply clicking on my C drive and received the following error

```
C:\ is not accessible
```

This is an SSD drive and contains all my apps and boot volume.
My PC otherwise boots ok and I also have an additional esata drive on the PC that I can access without any issues. I of course log in as administrator.

Thinking this was simply a matter of checking the permissions in properties, I right clicked the drive, choose properties and under security advanced get

```
Unable to display current owner
```

After a bit of googling I rebooted in safe mode and repeated the above with same results. A bit of googling later I tried installing a 3rd party utility 'lockhunter' but am unable to install, getting the message

```
Shell\ExecuteEx failed code 5. Access is denied.
```

Simply trying to launch TaskManager I get something similar

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the 
appropriate privileges to access the item.
```

I assume my next step would be to run some sort of diagnostics or permissions check thru the command console. But since I cannot launch task manager not sure how to even get an elevated command prompt. Can anyone help?

[edit]
Ok So I tried what I think is the ONLY way to get an elevated command prompt, via Command-X.  Regular cmd prompt, no problem. But when I try and launch an elevated prompt I get a new error

```
C:Users\foo\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\01
This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. 
Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association 
in the Default programs control panel.
```

Answer (score 1):

**[FixExec](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/fixexec/)** is a program that is designed to fix executable file associations for the .bat, .exe, and .com file extensions. If the program detects any of these associations are missing, changed, or hijacked, the settings will be set back to the original Windows defaults. When file associations for batch, executable, or COM files are changed it could cause your executables to no longer start. For example, when you double-click on a .bat, .exe, and .com file the programs will not start and Windows will ask what you would like to start the program with. **FixExec** is designed to resolve these issues by rebuilding the executable file association Windows Registry keys that have become damaged.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your drive is either failing, windows had an error or you have a virus. There is a couple of things you can try. First, I highly recommend a virus scan. Just use your favorite scanners. If you don't know of any I could recommend some free scanners.

Next, try Take ownership. Maybe the permissions on the drive are messed up and you can use this reg edit to take it back:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Third, remove the SDD, and place it into a new PC and see if a different PC is able to access the SDD. If not it could still be a virus or an error. You can also scan the drive for errors using /chkdsk while it's on the second PC.

Comment: Thanks. I tried installing takeownership but couldn't install for some reason. I also have Avira Antivirus Pro installed and turned on. I can launch it but when I try and do a scan I get the same permission error as when I try and launch Task Manager. My next step is to try and manually take ownership thru the command prompt but don't know how to get an elevated cmd prompt without Task Manager.

Comment: My next step was to try and take ownership thru an elevated command prompt. See my edit above

Comment: ok. Given up. In the process of creating a bootable USB flash drive with a Windows 10 ISO from my mac so I can reformat, reinstall Windows on my SSD. Painful and long process. However, I would like to know WHY this happened. Possible SSD drive error ? Is that even possible?